# jQuery clone link and wrap/appendto/replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, href, clone

I just want to clone the link provided (i.e. href="xxx", not all the junk in between) and put that link on another link elsewhere on the page.

This is the link I want to clone:

```
  <a href="/ReviewNew.asp?ProductCode=TRU%2DGDM49">
       <span class="PageText_L479n"> | 
          <span id="write">Write a review</span>
       </span>
  </a>
```

This is where I want to clone the link to (on id `sendreviewlink`):

```
<li id="sendreview">
     <a id="sendreviewlink" href=""><em>Write a Quick Review</em>
        <span class="hwText">Earn $2 For Every Approved Review</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```

This is my JavaScript code which I have tried so far:

```
$('#write').closest('a').clone().wrap('#sendreviewlink');
$('#write').closest('a').clone().appendTo('#sendreviewlink');
$('#write').closest('a').clone().ReplaceAll('#sendreviewlink');
```

Comment: Well, you should be getting at the `href` attribute then. Right now, you're trying to clone the whole element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just set the href like this

```
$('#sendreviewlink').attr('href',$('#write').closest('a').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

http://jsfiddle.net/bsXTM/

Not very polished tho, but ill leave that up to you.